# Using xarray groupby_bins results in coordinates that are an object and can't be saved in a netcdf file

Tags: python-xarray

I have data that I want to examine in different ways.  I want to look at histograms of different variables and averages as functions of different variables.  I'm iterating over big data with lots of files, so to speed things up I'm using groupby_bins with .sum and .cnt to save the info I need to synthesize at the end.
The issue I'm having is that there doesn't seem to be an easy way to save the data because the groupby_bins returns an xarray dataset with the coordinates set to a python object.  When I try to save data using .to_netcdf it yields and error because of the coordinate object....
Here is an example taken from the toy weather tutorial and edited a little:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns  # pandas aware plotting library
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(123)

times = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2001-12-31', name='time')
annual_cycle = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (times.dayofyear.values / 365.25 - 0.28))

base = 10 + 15 * annual_cycle.reshape(-1, 1)
tmin_values = base + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)
tmax_values = base + 10 + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)

ds = xr.Dataset({'tmin': (('time', 'location'), tmin_values),
                 'tmax': (('time', 'location'), tmax_values)},
                {'time': times, 'location': ['IA', 'IN', 'IL']})

freeze_bins = np.arange(-10,10,1)
freeze = ds.groupby_bins('tmin',freeze_bins).mean()
```

If you run this code you see that freeze looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (tmin_bins: 19)
Coordinates:
  * tmin_bins  (tmin_bins) object (-10, -9] (-9, -8] (-8, -7] ... (7, 8] (8, 9]
Data variables:
    tmin       (tmin_bins) float64 -9.535 -8.388 -7.512 ... 6.438 7.461 8.528
    tmax       (tmin_bins) float64 6.069 6.378 6.502 6.34 ... 16.41 18.06 19.27
```

and you get an error if you then try to save the data

```
freeze.to_netcdf('ohcrap.nc')
```

My late Saturday night solution leaves much to be desired:

```
freeze.coords['tmin_bins'] = freeze_bins[0:-1]  # could also use assign_coords
freeze.to_netcdf(slightlybetter.nc)
```

Any help appreciated.  Thanks, Chelle

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I think writing xarray objects to netCDF with interval indexes is not supported at this time. You may consider opening an issue on Xarray's Github page describing your use case.

As a short term stop gap, you are on the right path updating your bins coordinate. You can also get the midpoint from the Pandas IntervalIndex like this:

```
bin_labels = [v.mid for v in dsg['tmin_bins'].values]  # left/mid/right are options here
reeze.coords['tmin_bins'] = bin_labels
```

Comment: For reference see this Github issue: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2847#issue-424538928